# T-SQL UPSERT table with multiple values from TVP

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, upsert, table-valued-parameters

I use SQL Server 2012, and T-SQL as query language.

I need help updating/inserting multiple columns in [cross_function_user] using one ID value passed as a parameter (@userGroupID) and lots of function id's. They are List in C#, and passed to the sproc as Table Valued Parameter - with just one column of int, named Item.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [whatever]
    @userGroupID INT,
    @listID AS IntList READONLY
AS
BEGIN   
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE INTO [dbo].[cross_function_user] USING @listID
    ON [dbo].[cross_function_user].id_group_user = @userGroupID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET [cross_function_user].id_group_user = @userGroupID,
                   [cross_function_user].id_function = (SELECT Item FROM @listID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (id_group_user, id_function) 
        VALUES (@userGroupID, (SELECT Item FROM @listID) );

END
```

First, it errors 'subquery returned more than one result' of course, but I lack skill to rewrite this, and I'm not really sure if my upsert is written right way. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there only one column in IntList? What is it called? You need to refer to a column in your MERGE statement. In this example you can see that you should alias your TVP and refer to the columns in it http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/06/17/SQL-Server-2008---Killer-features---MERGE-and-Table-Valued-Parameters.aspx

Comment: Thank you, ElectriLlama, article in the link helped to work it out perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You need to replace YourColumn with the name of the column in your TVP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [whatever]
@userGroupID INT,
@listID AS IntList READONLY
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    MERGE INTO [dbo].[cross_function_user] USING @listID
    ON [dbo].[cross_function_user].id_group_user = @userGroupID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET [cross_function_user].id_function = S.YourColumn
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (id_group_user, id_function) 
        VALUES (@userGroupID, S.YourColumn);

END
```